# PHP preg_match to catch all but some options

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

What regex would I need to use to achieve the following;

Check if string does not contain one or more options... I tried a lot expressions. 
I think this is closest to be the correct one.

```
/^[^(256K)]$|^[^(2M)]$/
```

I would like preg_match to tell me if there is anything other than 256K or 2M, and I cant negate preg_match (!preg_match) for reasons that take to long to explain ;)

Comment: Ye im not gonna pretend that regex is my strongest card ;) Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: @RonnieJespersen the better question would be: "what are you doing right?" your regex is just a big syntax error ;)

Comment: I will make sure to read up on thoose pesky regex's ... I just needed a quick answer atm. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not place whole words or capturing groups inside of [Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). A *character class* matches any **one** character from a **set** of characters.

Your regular expression matches the beginning of the string, any character except: `(`, `2`, `5`, `6`, `K`, `)`, followed by the end of the string, **OR** the beginning of the string, any character except:  `(`, `2`, `M`, `)`, followed by the end of string.

I believe you are wanting a *Negative Lookahead* here instead.

```
/^((?!256K|2M).)*$/i
```

Regular expression:

```
^               # the beginning of the string
(               # group and capture to \1 (0 or more times)
(?!             # look ahead to see if there is not:
  256K          # '256K'
 |              # OR
  2M            # '2M'
)               # end of look-ahead
.               # any character except \n
)*              # end of \1 
$               # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Comment: Hi @hwnd I am trying your regex but I am not getting the result im looking for. /^((?!256K|10M).)*$/ (i just changed 2 to 10) in a preg_match gives me two results. "10m" and "m". The string that is testet is "10m". I need it to give no result if 256K or 10M is the string it self..

Comment: @RonnieJespersen your regex seems case-sensitive. if you want it to be case-insensitive, you have to use the `/i` switch...

Comment: Thanks @hwnd :) Looks like things are working now... and thanks for the exponentiation!